# A button with 3 pages, the 3rd one didn't work

Tags: java, android

I have a page that has a button, when you click it, it goes to another page with another button, when I click the button that takes to third page, it doesn't! I tried to make *MainActive2.java* and *PageOne2.java* but it didn't work! Help!

#### active_main.xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textStyle="italic" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/abus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="About us"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### abus.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/abus2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="About us"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

               </LinearLayout> 
           </ScrollView>          
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### abus2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical">

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:textStyle="italic"
                   android:textColor="#ffffff"
                   android:textSize="18sp"
                   android:text="Hello" />

           </LinearLayout> 
       </ScrollView>          
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.d.da;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abus);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PageOne.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

#### PageOne.java

```
package com.d.da;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PageOne extends Activity {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add OnClickListener to a button on second activity

**EDIT:**

```
package com.d.da;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PageOne extends Activity {

    Button button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abus);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }


    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abus2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I did! button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { .. Unless I'm losing something!

Comment: Take a look at PageOne.java. I don't see any listener... Maybe you didn't paste it here?

Comment: I didn't add it yet it seems, can you tell me what to add exactly in PageOne?

Comment: No it's not :( the abus2 has a red line underneath it!

Comment: Try to clean project. You have abus2 in your layout!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PageOne extends Activity {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abus);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abus2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
               //do things here
               Intent intent = new Intent(PageOne.this, OtherActivity.class);
               PageOne.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, you honestly should use some more descriptive IDs. You ARE going to have access to them throughout the application via the R resource class, which means having abus1 abus2 abus3 abus4 abus5 in your activities will eventually get extremely confusing.

Comment: Both of the works (but) button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abus2) gives me a red line under abus2 but it doesn't in PageOne